# How to create serial TridentState bolts using partitionpersist in Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I was able to process a stream of events in batches using the partitionpersist api provided with TridentState. But now, I want to emit the processed values of this bolt and collect them as another batch of events in a following bolt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state.newValuesStream()` method on your TridentState does exactly that -- it returns a stream of newly updated values from your TridentState.

Comment: I did it this way. Was actually facing another problem. Thanks for the answer though.